# How to prevent celery from initializing tasks twice

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

I'm trying to create a crawler using Celery. The general structure of the application is

- Celery workers having access to a browser pool
- When a task is delayed, it picks one browser from the pool and use that browser
- There is a separated client script which calls the `.delay()` method on the tasks

Here's a minimal example:

Folder structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── app.py
    ├── browser_pool.py
    └── tasks.py
```

```py
## tasks.py 

from myapp.app import app
from myapp.browser_pool import BrowserPoolSingleton

class BaseTask(app.Task):
    def __init__(self):
        # all tasks in the application should have access to this pool
        self.pool = BrowserPoolSingleton.get()

    def other_methods(self):
        ...

@app.task(base=BaseTask, bind=True)
def task_goto(self, url: str):
    session = self.pool.get()
    session.get(url)
    self.pool.release(session)
```

```py
## app.py 

from celery import Celery

app = Celery("example-application", broker="redis://localhost:6379")
app.autodiscover_tasks(["myapp.tasks"])
```

And this is my client script:

```py
## main.py
from myapp.tasks import task_goto

task_goto.delay("https://google.com")
```

When I start the workers, a pool is started just as expected. But when I run the main script, the pool is started again, so now there are two instances of the pool running in two separated Python processes.
While the delayed tasks correctly use the first pool running in the workers, the second pool just keeps running and do nothing until the main script exits.

Is there any way to prevent the second pool from starting up? If retrieve the pool singleton directly in the task functions without using a base class like above, another new pool is spun up every time I delay a task.